# ¿Como funcionan estos métodos?

Tags: java

public class Principal {

```
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String nombre;

public static int id;

public static int opc;

public static Vector<Figura> figuras = new Vector();

public static void main4(String[] args) {

    do {
        menu();
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:

                altaTriangulo();

                break;

            case 2:

                altaCuadrado();

                break;

            case 3:

                altaPentagono();

                break;

            case 4:

                altaCirculo();

                break;

            case 5:

                imprimirBD();

                break;

            case 6:

                bajarFigura();

                break;

            case 7:
                System.out.println("Adios!");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Digitaste un numero diferente. Digita de 1 a 6");
                break;
        }

    } while (opc != 7);
}

public static void menu() {

    System.out.println("MENU FIGURAS");
    System.out.println("1. alta triangulos");
    System.out.println("2. alta cuadrados");
    System.out.println("3. alta pentagonos");
    System.out.println("4. alta circulos");
    System.out.println("5. imprimirBD");
    System.out.println("6. dar de baja figuras");
    System.out.println("7. Salir");

    opc = sc.nextInt();
}

public static void altaTriangulo() {
    id = leerId();
    System.out.println("Escribe el nombre del triangulo: ");
    nombre = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Digita la base del triangulo: ");
    double base = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digita la altura del triangulo: ");
    double altura = sc.nextDouble();

    figuras.addElement(new Triangulo(base, altura, id, nombre));
}

public static int leerId() {
    boolean duplicado = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Dame el id  de la figura: ");
        id = sc.nextInt();
        duplicado = validarIdDuplicado(id);
        if (duplicado) {
            System.out.println("Este id esta repetido!!");
        }
    } while (duplicado);
    return id;
}

public static boolean validarIdDuplicado(int id) {
    boolean retorno = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < figuras.size(); i++) {
        if (id == figuras.elementAt(i).getId()) {
            retorno = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

esta clase se encarga de pedir al usuario que elija un tipo de figuras con el switch y de ahí se mande al método respectivo, en este caso mande llamar al método triangulo solamente porque es muy largo el código, en ese método se implemente otro que se llama leerId() el cual no ayuda a ver si cuando ingresamos un id ese no este repetido en el vector y si es así nos vuelva a pedir que reingrese un código nuevo..

No entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento de el método leerId() y el método validarIdDuplicado() en su totalidad y quería ver si alguien es capaz de explicarme como funcionan de un mejor manera. Si necesitan el proyecto completo mándeme mensaje y con gusto se lo paso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entiendo que el flujo es el siguiente:

1. se ejecuta metodo main
2. se obtiene el valor opc del scan
3. pasa al switch
4. el opc en este escenario tiene el valor de 1, por lo que pasa a alta triangulo
5. altaTriangulo(), se ejecuta y este a su vez ejecuta leerId()
6. leerId() tiene la intencion de generar un id al nuevo triangulo que se va a agregar al vector de figuras
7. el id dentro de leerId() se genera del siguen int encontrado por el scan
8. Se ejecuta el metodo validarDuplicado
9. validarDuplicado() tiene como valor inicial a retorno como false, pero al ser la primera vez que se ejecuta ele metodo el vector esta vacio por lo que no cumple con la validacion del for haciendo que devuelva false
10. si devuelve false, ya nuevamente en el metodo leerId() no va a cumplir con la validacion de duplicado y va a devolver el id primera vez ingresado
11. este id se vuelve parte de un nuevo objecto figura dentro de vector
12. termino la primera iteracion del flujo de alta de figuras

Que pasa si vuelves a ejecutarlo?

13. Vuelves a querer dar de alta a caulquer figura (para este ejemplo usare nuevamente triangulo) e ingresas el mismo id de la figura anterior
14. ingresa a alta triangulo y se ejecuta leerId()
15. ingresas el mismo id anterior
16. va hacia validarDuplicado
17. validar duplicado ya tiene un size de 1, entonces sera valido ingresar al for y figurar[0] tiene el primer id que ingresaste, por lo que ahora devolvera true como valor de repetido, impidiendote dar de alta a la figura

Seria todo. Espero ayude

Comment: Gracias hermano!!!